# Custom django management command to populate countries with pycountry AttributeError

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to create a custom command to populate countries in admin from pycountry package. But I am getting confusing AttributeError that says I am not referencing it correctly. Can someone help me to identify my mistake?

Project settings for management command is:

```
market/ 
    manage.py
    address/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        management/
            __init__.py
            commands/
                __init__.py
                market_populate_countries.py
        views.py
```

Management command code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
from optparse import make_option
from default.core.loading import get_model
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Populates the list of countries with data from pycountry."
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option(
            '--no-shipping',
            action='store_false',
            dest='is_shipping',
            default=True,
            help="Don't mark countries for shipping"),
        make_option(
            '--initial-only',
            action='store_true',
            dest='is_initial_only',
            default=False,
            help="Exit quietly without doing anything if countries were already populated."),
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            import pycountry
        except ImportError:
            raise CommandError(
                "You are missing the pycountry library. Install it with "
                "'pip install pycountry'")

        if Country.objects.exists():
            if options.get('is_initial_only', False):
                # exit quietly, as the initial load already seems to have happened.
                self.stdout.write("Countries already populated; nothing to be done.")
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                raise CommandError(
                    "You already have countries in your database. This command "
                    "currently does not support updating existing countries.")

        countries = [
            Country(
                iso_3166_1_a2=country.alpha2,
                iso_3166_1_a3=country.alpha3,
                iso_3166_1_numeric=country.numeric,
                printable_name=country.name,
                name=getattr(country, 'official_name', ''),
                is_shipping_country=options['is_shipping'])
            for country in pycountry.countries]

        Country.objects.bulk_create(countries)
        self.stdout.write("Successfully added %s countries." % len(countries))
```

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\Alikhan\amazonclone\market>manage.py market_populate_countries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alikhan\amazonclone\market\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 394,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 445,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Alikhan\amazonclone\market\address\management\commands\market_
populate_countries.py", line 56, in handle
    for country in pycountry.countries]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycountry\db.py", line 22, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

This is irrelevant but following is the way I've customized source function for get_model to avoid any confusion.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
import traceback
from importlib import import_module

from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import MODELS_MODULE_NAME
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import AppRegistryNotReady

from .exceptions import (
    AppNotFoundError, ClassNotFoundError, ModuleNotFoundError)

def get_model(app_label, model_name):
    try:
        return apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
    except AppRegistryNotReady:
        if apps.apps_ready and not apps.models_ready:
            app_config = apps.get_app_config(app_label)
            import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, MODELS_MODULE_NAME))
            return apps.get_registered_model(app_label, model_name)
        else:
            raise
```

Comment: Is that the full error? Does it really not say what attribute is giving the error?

Comment: Yes this is what is surprising for me. I can reference in shell and can see list of countries. Not working in code.

Comment: What is `pycountry` and `countries`?

Comment: Its a package and maintained one. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry. Country is a model in "address" app to extract and hold countries from pycountry package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pycountry`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry) appears to have the number separated for alpha_2 and 3

`country.alpha2` and  `country.alpha3` should be `country.alpha_2` and  `country.alpha_3`  respectively

---

After changing the above, your code should become

```
    countries = [
        Country(
            iso_3166_1_a2=country.alpha_2,
            iso_3166_1_a3=country.alpha_3,
            iso_3166_1_numeric=country.numeric,
            printable_name=country.name,
            name=getattr(country, 'official_name', ''),
            is_shipping_country=options['is_shipping'])
        for country in pycountry.countries]
```

Comment: @Alikhan - Are you sure you changed both? I received the same error as you before changing and after it works fine - [pastebin of output](http://pastebin.com/nHPjPtwG)

Comment: I've double checked and yes it is same error. Let me try one more time by re-writing the whole code so I can visualize any possible mistake.

Comment: @Alikhan - The only possible things different between my test code and yours is the version of `pycountry` you're using (I just did pip install pycountry) and the `options['is_shipping']` where I just substituted in False, try to use my input in a shell of your own to see if that works

Comment: Same error. I am using pycountry 1.10. Can you tell me your version? Coz I am on Django LTS 1.8.16, and this pycountry version is compatible.

Comment: @Alikhan - It would have been `17.1.8`,  I just tried using `1.10` and that does use `alpha2` and `alpha3` but that also works fine for me (the only difference again would be the `options['is_shipping']`)

Comment: I've upgraded to latest version that is compatible to LTS that I missed before. I am still getting same error. Can you please let me have your version that solved the issue? I will amend pycountry source according to your solution.

Comment: @Alikhan - I just did `pip install pycountry` and then `pip install pycountry==1.10`, I'm not sure how much more I'd be able to help, try to reproduce the error inside a python console on its own using the code from my previous pastebin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133334/discussion-between-ali-khan-and-sayse).

Comment: I added full code as proposed and it worked. Before I was just adding one line. Thanks for help and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Alikhan - no worries, enjoy!